# What is the best way to cache a table from a (SQL) linked server view?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have a view that retrieves data from/through a linked server, thus when calling the linked table through the view I will use `select * from linkerserver.linkedtable`. My query works and I get a table of info back.

I am however concerned about speed and contention when using a linked server especially if there are multiple users accessing/calling a *sp* (Stored Procedure) that makes use of the Linked Server View.

I am unsure as to how I could solve this problem or even if it is a problem? (Will one face speed or contention issues when using a linked server view?).

The options to get around this could be:

1. Create a persistent temporary table (##MYTEMP) that is a duplicate of the data/table from the view, but exists locally.
2. All calls are then directed to this temp table existing locally.
3. or create a duplicate table locally and have a trigger to populate this table after the first call of the day.

Any advise about how to solve this problem or best use case would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How often do you need this table updated?  Most solutions I have heard of would use SSIS to push new data periodically (Weekly, nightly, hourly...)

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the message. Essentially the data in the table is only updated once a day, so I only need it updated once a day say in the morning. It's on a separate server loaded by a different team. I make use of the data through the linked-server. I am concerned though of speed issues as the info.table is big. Thus my idea of caching it. I'm just not sure best practice for implementing this....tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best bet would be to ask the other team to push you the data after they update it.  If they are only adding new records this is all you need added to your table.  If they are also updating data then they could use Merge so that only new records and changes are processed.

My second choice would be to have a table on your server that gets dropped and re-pulled (or use Merge) from the linked server once they do their data load.  You would need to coordinate with their team on this.

My last choice would be to have this data pulled nightly by SQL Agent.  Unless the source data was also updated nightly, then this would be my second choice.  If they processed between midnight and 2 am I would have my job run at 3 or 4am.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to write the result of a `SELECT` into a table. All columns will be created automatically:

```
SELECT * INTO NewTable FROM linkerserver.linkedtable
```

The `NewTable` can be a normal table as well as a `#` or a `##`.

After usage (or right before) you just drop this table...

Comment: Thank You Shungo. I understand this, but I only need to do the select into my temp table if my table is out of date. and for every query that uses the temporary table I somehow need to make sure it's out of date first. It's essentially this step I wanted clarity on.

Comment: @765tgs What about a nightly job which drops your table and fills it automatically? If you do not want a gap (if your table is used 24 hours) you could try this: Load your data into a `tempA`. Next night you load it into `tempB`, next night drop A and re-read it, next night drop B and re-read it. Your processes use a `VIEW` to read the data. The final step after re-filling was a simple `ALTER VIEW` statement...

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this problem in the past.
What I notice from my experience is that the sql server doesn't generate the best query plans when it comes to link server.

How big is the database that have this table ? Is it possible to do replicate read only ?

If yes, then it's better to do that. If not, then you will need just like you said, a local table and a trigger. Or an incremental update using sql agent every 5 minutes or so.

Comment: Essentially > 10,000 rows, 20 Columns. Yes replicate read-only is an option. I like your idea of an incremental update though.

Comment: When doing replication, you can't just replicate a table, you need to replicate the database. So that's why I was asking how big is the database. If it's not big, then replicate read only is way better than incremental update using sql agent, because you don't need to re invent the wheel.

Comment: I hear you. The DB is massive and much of the data on it will be restricted for my access .....

Comment: Ah, yes, then sorry buddy, no options for you. :(